# IFilter ErrorCode FILTER_E_ACCESS when reading .rtf (Rick Text format) from byte array

Tags: c#, ifilter

I'm using this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31944/Implementing-a-TextReader-to-extract-various-files and it's mostly working.

I wrote this test to check if the Filter would read as expected from a byte array.

```
private const string ExpectedText = "This is a test!";
[Test]
public void FilterReader_RtfBytes_TextMatch()
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Test Documents\DocTest.rtf");
    var reader = new FilterReader(bytes, ".rtf");
    reader.Init();
    var actualText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    StringAssert.Contains(ExpectedText, actualText);
}
```

The test fails with [ErrorCode : FILTER_E_ACCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it works fine when I give it the filename.

```
new FilterReader(@"Test Documents\DocTest.rtf", ".rtf"); <-- works
```

I'm puzzled as to why that is. I looked through the code and it seems it's the rtf filter dll that returns the error. Which is even more puzzling.

It works fine for other file types, like; .doc, .docx, .pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

under the hood the using of concrete way of work with iFilter is defined by constructor: when you use constructor `FilterReader(byte[] bytes, string extension)` is used IPersistStream for content loading from memory, when `FilterReader(string path, string extension)` - IPersistFile for loading from file.

why rtf-ifilter returns error when used with IPersistStream i'm afraid we will not able to know because source code isn't opened

in my case i encapsulate filter's specific in constructor and refactor code next way:

- remove all constructors
- remove `public void Init()`-method
- implement one custom constructor `public FilterReader(string fileName, string extension, uint blockSize = 0x2000)`:

  ```
  #region Contracts

  Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName));
  Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension));
  Contract.Requires(blockSize > 1);

  #endregion

  const string rtfExtension = ".rtf";

  FileName = fileName;
  Extension = extension;
  BufferSize = blockSize;

  _buffer = new char[ActBufferSize];

  // ! Take into account that Rtf-file can be loaded only using IPersistFile.
  var doUseIPersistFile = string.Compare(rtfExtension, extension, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;

  // Initialize _filter instance.
  try
  {
      if (doUseIPersistFile)
      {
          // Load content using IPersistFile.
          _filter = FilterLoader.LoadIFilterFromIPersistFile(FileName, Extension);
      }
      else
      {
          // Load content using IPersistStream.
          using (var stream = new FileStream(path: fileName, mode: FileMode.Open, access: FileAccess.Read, share: FileShare.Read))
          {
              var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
              stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

              _filter = FilterLoader.LoadIFilterFromStream(buffer, Extension);
          }
      }
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException)
  {
      throw;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      throw new AggregateException(message: string.Format("Filter Not Found or Loaded for extension '{0}'.", Extension), innerException: e);
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah, some IFilters do not implement both IPersistStream and IPersistFile. I'm guessing the RTF IFilter is just really old and unimportant and they didn't think about implementing the other interface.  In Windows 10, and new Adobe pdf IFilters do not even support IPersistFile